# SSH Connection refused only from one computer

Tags: networking, server, ssh

I'm trying to connect via SSH to an ubuntu machine that we use for computing at work.

Normally everything works fine, however yesterday I tried to setup a password-less login following [this guide](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-setup-passwordless-ssh-login/). In the end, that didn't work so I removed the file ~/.ssh/authorized_keys (actually, I backed it up). Now, whenever I try to connect I get

```
$ ssh -vvvv user@x.x.x.x
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "x.x.x.x" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to x.x.x.x [x.x.x.x] port 22.
debug1: connect to address x.x.x.x port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host x.x.x.x port 22: Connection refused
```

I know this is a very common problem, however there's a major difference compared to all the other similar problems I managed to find online.

It looks like this only happens from a single computer:

1. If I try to ssh from my computer to that server, I get the connection refused error.
2. If I try to ssh into the server from my laptop, for example, or any other machine everything works fine.
3. If someone else tries to log into the server with their username *from my machine*, they also get the connection refused error.
4. If I want to connect from my machine to any other ssh server it works fine, including other servers in my workplace.

It really looks like that server doesn't like my computer. I know that the best advice is to contact the admin of the server, but the IT here is incredibly slow...

Any ideas on what could be the problem?

Comment: have you tried to connect with your user from another computer? It sounds like they have something like fail2ban or denyhosts which has blacklisted your IP

Comment: yes I tried and it works from other computers. I guess that if is one of the problems you described this can only be solved by the admin, right?

Comment: Yes this needs someone with elevated privileges to investigate. My answers were just guesses though it could be anything. Without being able to look at the logs its impossible to know